# AngularJs ng-style ::after

Tags: css, angularjs, styles

I'm trying to edit the border-bottom-color individual depending on a property of the element in ng-repeat.

Here is an example how the html is structured. The changed style is 
`.active-tool::after {border-bottom-color: rgb(247, 153, 248)}`

html:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="row in rows">
        <div class='container'>
            <div 
                data-ng-style="getPrimaryColor(tvShow)" 
                class='folder tvshow' 
                data-ng-class="isActiveFolder(tvShow)" 
                id='{{tvShow.id}}' 
                data-ng-repeat="tvShow in row track by $index">

                <div data-ng-click="setSelectedTvShow(tvShow)">
                    <p class="tvshow-name">{{tvShow.name}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

controller.js

```
$scope.isActiveFolder = function(tvShow) {
        if($scope.selectedTvShow !== null && tvShow.id !== null) {
           return $scope.selectedTvShow===tvShow.id ? 'active-tool' : '';
        }
    };

    $scope.getPrimaryColor = function(tvShow) {
       if($scope.selectedTvShow !== null) {
           var result = '{' + tvShow.id + '.active-tool::after {border-bottom-color: rgb(247, 153, 248)}}';
           console.log(result);
           return result;
       };
```

Any ideas how this could be done?

Answer (score 5):

I use this quick hack:

put this inside your template:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .active-tool::after {
        border-bottom-color: {{getShowBorderColor(tvShow)}};
    }
</style>
```

and then in your controller:

```
$scope.getShowBorderColor = function(tvShow){
    return tvShow.color; // change this for how you want to calculate the color
};
```

Comment: does this still work? I haven't been able to get angular handlebars to work inside css

Comment: it's not in the css. It's in the html (template) file which contains this style tag.

Comment: That was the only way that I found to make it work with :after/:before. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ng-style` like this, because **html style attribute does not support css selectors**.

Actually, you can do it with no javascript at all:

**markup:**

```
<div data-ng-repeat="row in rows">
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='folder tvshow' 
             data-ng-class="{active-tool : selectedTvShow === tvShow.id}" 
             id='{{tvShow.id}}' 
             data-ng-repeat="tvShow in row track by $index">

            <div data-ng-click="selectedTvShow = tvShow.id">
                <p class="tvshow-name">{{tvShow.name}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css:**

```
.active-tool::after {
  border-bottom-color: rgb(247, 153, 248);
}
```

Comment: Thank you,but the goal is to calculate the color for the border-bottom-color.