# How do I use ng-style with div:after?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-directive

I'm using Angular 1.x.

Here's [code example](https://jsfiddle.net/bz2t7va1/#fork) on jsfiddle.

If `ctrl.shouldShowDiv2 = false` I don't wanna show `div2` otherwise (`ctrl.shouldShowDiv2 = true`) I wanna activate `box::after`. Is there a way to make it work with `ng-style` or any other directive?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21367886) looks similar to what I want but I couldn't understand it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Tony. Your question, as you presented it, won't be of use of anybody else (especially if you delete your jsfiddle, which probably will happen). Paste some code instead and show what have you tried. That would let people help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is create a separate class that you use the `::after` selector on. Then you toggle that class using your `ctrl.shouldShowDiv2`. Here's an example:

```js
angular.module('app', []);
```

```css
.box {
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background: tomato;
}

.box-xtra::after {
  content: "div2";
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: -30px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.2/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <div style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
    <label>Show div2 <input type="checkbox" ng-model="ctrl.shouldShowDiv2" /></label>
  </div>
  <div class="box" ng-class="{'box-xtra': ctrl.shouldShowDiv2}"></div>
</div>
```